# How to perform Load test for Lazy loading in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

We need to perform Load test with Jmeter for Lazy Loading.
for the first request it loads around 16-18 list of data > When scroll down it loads more.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the network tab of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and get the request associated with loading of extra data when you're doing the scrolling and create the relevant [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to mimic this request. Repeat as per your test scenario.

Alternatively you can record the call using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).

You can also consider adding a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to simulate user reading the data and/or taking the time to scroll down.